# C++ External function with pointer to function as parameter, used inside a class with a member function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, std-function

Fairly new to C++. Suppose I have a class:

```
class A
{
private:
    double m_x, m_y;
public:
    A(double x, double y): m_x {x}
    {
        m_y = extF(m_x, y, *intF);
    }

    double intF(double x) { return 2*x; }
};
```

And it makes use of an external global function, defined elsewhere:

```
double extF(double x, double y, std::function<double(double)> f)
{
    if (x*y < 0)
        return f(x);
    else
        return f(y);
}
```

Formulas are bogus. This does not compile. I tried simple `intF`, `A::*intF`, `&A::intF`, even some unorthodox combinations, but that's just guessing. The problem is that class `A` is not the only one which makes use of the global external function and it's something that should be able to be a user choice at runtime. Searches revealed some answers saying it's not possible to make a pointer to a member function like this because it needs instantiation(?), but I found no solutions. Can this be done? If yes, how?

---

Edit: Additional question: how can the pointer to member function be done if the member function is `const double f(...) const`?

Comment: Make `intF` static member function if it won't access any members of the class.

Comment: @songyuanyao Unfortunately, it does. If I knew this was a problem, I would have modified the code to show.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Not your fault, but mine. I went OT first, lets delete these comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One variant is just to use lambda:

```
class A
{
private:
    double m_x, m_y;
public:
    A(double x, double y): m_x {x}
    {
         m_y = extF(m_x, y, [&](double d){ return intF(d);});
    }

    double intF(double x) { return 2*x; }
};
```

Another variant is to use lambda and [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) (omitting the rest code of your class):

```
A(double x, double y): m_x {x}
{
    auto fn = std::mem_fn(&A::intF);
    m_y = extF(m_x, y, [&](double d) {return fn(this, d);});
}
```

And finally you may get rid of lambdas if you [bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) the object parameter of member function pointer:

```
A(double x, double y): m_x {x}
{
    auto fn1 = std::bind(std::mem_fn(&A::intF), this, std::placeholders::_1);
    m_y = extF(m_x, y, fn1);
}
```

All these also work with constant member functions.

Comment: Thank you, both (@songuyanyao and you), for your answers. I don't know about the `std::mem_fn` and `std::bind` yet. I'll read about them now.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to bind the member function.

```
A(double x, double y): m_x {x}
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    m_y = extF(m_x, y, std::bind(&A::intF, this, _1));
}
```

Or use a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

```
A(double x, double y): m_x {x}
{
    m_y = extF(m_x, y, [this](double d) { return intF(d); });
}
```

BTW: It works well with const member function too, which doesn't matter here.

[LIVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a577d511467af3f)